# Calculate the moment generating function with given probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, moment-generating-functions

I have the following Information for $x_i$ and its probabilities $p_i$:

$x_i = -1 \rightarrow p_i = 0,1$

$x_i = 0 \rightarrow p_i = 0,5$

$x_i = 2 \rightarrow p_i = 0,3$

$x_i = 3,5 \rightarrow p_i = 0,1$

I have to calculate the expectation, variance, skewness as well as the Moment generating funciton $M(t) = E[e^{tX}]$.

I've started with the expectation as follows: $E[X] = -1 \cdot 0,1+0 \cdot 0,5+2 \cdot 0,3+3,5 \cdot0,1 = 0,85$

I've continued with the usual formulas for variance and skewness. How can I calculate the mgf? Thank you!

Comment: Use the forumla for $E[f(X)]$, just as you did for variance/skew. It'll be the sum of exponentials with weights equal to the probabilities.

Comment: Of course, thank you!